# how to get a Combobox selection to display related information in labels?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, combobox

Im trying to get my labels to display information based off of my cbo selection.  (i.e. cbo = Class Name then the labels would show class title and units.)

```
Dim l As Integer

'Connect to Database and get the registration information
Using cnnOLEDB = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)

    ' Query the classschedule table for start of semester datas
    Using cmdOleDB = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [CourseTitle], [ShortTitle],[Units] FROM [Course]", cnnOLEDB)
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        Using rdrOLEDB = cmdOleDB.ExecuteReader
            While rdrOLEDB.Read

                CboCourse.Items.Add(rdrOLEDB.Item(0).ToString)



                CourseArray(l, 0) = rdrOLEDB.Item(0).ToString
                CourseArray(l, 1) = rdrOLEDB.Item(1).ToString
                CourseArray(l, 2) = rdrOLEDB.Item(2).ToString
                l = l + 1

                lblCourseTitle.Text = (rdrOLEDB.Item(1).ToString)
                lblUnits.Text = (rdrOLEDB.Item(2).ToString)

                ' CboFormat.Items.Add()
                ' CboDayTime.Items.Add()
                ' CboLocation.Items.Add()
                ' CboName.Items.Add()
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

I know this is probably easy to do but i can not figure this out.
my information is in an array thats being read from a MS-access database

Comment: The penny may be about to drop... you only have `rdrOLEDB.Item(0)` (Title?) in the cbo, so in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event you will have to find it in that array to post (x,1) and (x,2) to the labels.  If the cbo was bound to a list of Course objects, you could just use `cbo.SelectedItem.ShortTitle` etc.  Since you have to shuttle them into that array, you ought to bite the bullet and use a list and save lots of time and coding horrors elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data binding to make working with data sweet and easy.

In the below code we set up labels to use data binding and use the combo box as index. So when you choose a course from the combo box, the labels will automatically show related data:

```
'Setup connection and command
Dim Connection As String = "Your connection string here"
Dim Command As String = "SELECT [CourseTitle], [ShortTitle],[Units] FROM [Course]"
Dim DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(Command, Connection)
Dim Table As New DataTable()

'Load data
DataAdapter.Fill(Table)

'Set data bindings
Me.ShortTitleLabel.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Table, "ShortTitle"))
Me.UnitsLabel.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Table, "Units"))

'Use a data bound combo box as index
Me.CourseComboBox.DataSource = Table
Me.CourseComboBox.DisplayMember = "CourseTitle"
```

Don't forget to import `Imports System.Data.OleDb`

Comment: you sir are amazing, this simplified things so much. Im still a novice at this coding stuff, but thank you so much.

Comment: with this i should be able to modify things a bit to add in the other cbo selections correct?
just modify the cmd str and add in the data bindings

Comment: You should use just one combo box as index, like when you use a list box or a grid as index, then use other controls to show other data.

Comment: By the way, while you can accept only one answer, but you can kindly vote up as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near answers. Also you can vote for good questions.  It's not compulsory at all, but makes questions and answers more useful for future readers :)

Comment: Sorry i mean for a similar issue. not this one exactly, i also checked yours and upvoted the others as well. 
you were my first upvote haha

Comment: Yes you can use such code for all combo boxes, but be aware, we used this combo box just as an index (table of content) and if you want to use a combo box for editing, you should also set the `ValueMember` and also add data binding.

Comment: To learn more, you can see this example: [ComboBox Databinding](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ComboBox-Databinding-ab61d9d5)

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest you to avoid the ArrayList class. This is one of the first collection classes available in the NET Framework but now we have a great variety of choice to store object instances in a collection. For your case a List(Of T) is probably more than enough.

So let's start defining our T (A Course class)

```
Public Class Course
    Public Title As String
    Public ShortTitle As String
    Public Units As Integer
End Class
```

With this class in place you could declare, instead of a typeless ArrayList a List(Of Course)

```
Dim courseList = New List(Of Course)
```

and the code that reads data from your db becomes

```
.....
Using rdrOLEDB = cmdOleDB.ExecuteReader
    While rdrOLEDB.Read
        Dim cc = New Course()
        cc.Title = rdrOLEDB.Item(0).ToString
        cc.ShortTitle = rdrOLEDB.Item(1).ToString
        cc.Units = Convert.ToInt32(rdrOLEDB.Item(2))
        courseList.Add(cc)
    End While
End Using
```

At the end of the loop and after closing all the using statements set the DataSource of your combo to the courseList

```
cboCourse.DataSource = courseList
cboCourse.DisplayMember = "Title"
cboCourse.ValueMember = "Title"
```

At this point, inside the SelectedIndexChanged event handler you could retrieve your selected item in this way

```
Sub cboCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cbo = CType(sender, ComboBox )
    Dim cc = CType(cbo.SelectedItem, Course)
    If cc IsNot Nothing
        lblCourseTitle.Text = cc.ShortTitle
        lblUnits.Text = cc.Units.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set the DataSource of the ComboBox as shown above?